# PHP executes an older version of a script that I've already overwritten

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

I'm literally freaking out. It's the first time such a thing happens to me.
I have modified and saved a php script, and now I am calling it from the browser, and the old version is still being run.

No, I'm not seing a version of a page cached by the browser. I am using the Yii framework and I'm looking at the application's logs. I can vim the php file on the server and see that it's the new version. Yet, when i do a request from the browser, and then look at the logs, the new traces that show up in the logs indicate that it's the old version running. That version doesn't exist any more, it's been overwritten.

I think the PHP engine is using some cached version of the compiled bytecode, not realising (for some reason) that the script has been modified and the cached compiled version is obsolete. This is clearly some awful bug in some piece of server sofware (php itself? zend engine? whatever...). The question is: how do I workaround it? How do I clear this kind of cache to force the recompilation of all script files?

Output of phpinfo:

```
> PHP Version 5.1.6
> 
> 
> System    Linux ks3094309.kimsufi.com 2.6.38.2-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #1 SMP
> Tue Apr 12 17:19:35 UTC 2011 x86_64 Build Date    Nov 29 2010 16:49:11
> Configure Command  './configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
> '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
> '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr'
> '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
> '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include'
> '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec'
> '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com'
> '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info'
> '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64'
> '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
> '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug'
> '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2'
> '--with-curl' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr'
> '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm'
> '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr'
> '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr'
> '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU'
> '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes'
> '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm'
> '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid'
> '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos'
> '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr'
> '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar'
> '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio'
> '--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime' '--without-sqlite'
> '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--with-system-tzdata'
> '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd'
> '--without-odbc' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC'
> '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' Server
> API   Apache 2.0 Handler Virtual Directory Support    disabled
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php.ini Scan this dir for
> additional .ini files /etc/php.d additional .ini files
> parsed    /etc/php.d/dbase.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/gd.ini,
> /etc/php.d/imap.ini, /etc/php.d/ioncube-loader.ini,
> /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
> /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
> /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite.ini,
> /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php.d/xsl.ini
> PHP API   20041225 PHP Extension  20050922 Zend Extension 220051025 Debug
> Build no Thread Safety    disabled Zend Memory Manager    enabled IPv6
> Support   enabled Registered PHP Streams  php, file, http, ftp,
> compress.bzip2, compress.zlib, https, ftps Registered Stream Socket
> Transports    tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls Registered
> Stream Filters    string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower,
> string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, convert.iconv.*, bzip2.*,
> zlib.*
> 
> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
> Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
>     with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.28, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by ionCube Ltd.
> 
> PHP Credits
> 
> Configuration
> 
> PHP Core
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> allow_call_time_pass_reference    Off Off allow_url_fopen On  On
> always_populate_raw_post_data Off Off arg_separator.input &   &
> arg_separator.output  &   & asp_tags  Off Off auto_append_file    no value    no
> value auto_globals_jit    On  On auto_prepend_file    no value    no value
> browscap  no value    no value default_charset    no value    no value
> default_mimetype  text/html   text/html define_syslog_variables   Off Off
> disable_classes   no value    no value disable_functions  no value    no value
> display_errors    Off Off display_startup_errors  Off Off doc_root    no
> value no value docref_ext no value    no value docref_root    no value    no
> value enable_dl   On  On error_append_string  no value    no value
> error_log no value    no value error_prepend_string   no value    no value
> error_reporting   2047    2047 expose_php On  On
> extension_dir /usr/lib64/php/modules  /usr/lib64/php/modules
> file_uploads  On  On highlight.bg #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
> highlight.comment #FF8000 #FF8000 highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
> highlight.html    #000000 #000000 highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
> highlight.string  #DD0000 #DD0000 html_errors On  On
> ignore_repeated_errors    Off Off ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
> ignore_user_abort Off Off implicit_flush  Off Off
> include_path  .:/usr/share/pear:  .:/usr/share/pear: log_errors   On  On
> log_errors_max_len    1024    1024 magic_quotes_gpc   Off Off
> magic_quotes_runtime  Off Off magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
> mail.force_extra_parameters   no value    no value max_execution_time 30  30
> max_file_uploads  20  20 max_input_nesting_level  64  64
> max_input_time    1000    60 memory_limit 128M    128M
> open_basedir  /var/www/vhosts/megafone.net/httpdocs:/tmp:/usr/share/pear  no value output_buffering   4096    4096 output_handler no value    no value
> post_max_size 200M    8M precision    14  14 realpath_cache_size  16K 16K
> realpath_cache_ttl    120 120 register_argc_argv  Off Off
> register_globals  Off Off register_long_arrays    Off Off
> report_memleaks   On  On report_zend_debug    On  On safe_mode    Off Off
> safe_mode_exec_dir    no value    no value safe_mode_gid  Off Off
> safe_mode_include_dir no value    no value sendmail_from  no value    no
> value sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
> serialize_precision   100 100 short_open_tag  On  On
> SMTP  localhost   localhost smtp_port 25  25 sql.safe_mode    Off Off
> track_errors  Off Off unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
> upload_max_filesize   50M 2M upload_tmp_dir   no value    no value
> user_dir  no value    no value variables_order    EGPCS   EGPCS
> xmlrpc_error_number   0   0 xmlrpc_errors Off Off y2k_compliance  On  On
> zend.ze1_compatibility_mode   Off Off
> 
> apache2handler
> 
> Apache Version    Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Apache API Version    20051115
> Server Administrator  abadantoni@gmail.com
> Hostname:Port megafone.net:80 User/Group  apache(48)/48 Max
> Requests  Per Child: 4000 - Keep Alive: off - Max Per Connection: 100
> Timeouts  Connection: 120 - Keep-Alive: 15 Virtual Server Yes Server
> Root  /etc/httpd Loaded Modules   core prefork http_core mod_so
> mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias
> mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host
> mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm
> mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config
> mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires
> mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav
> mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias
> mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias
> mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http
> mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache
> mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_ssl mod_bw mod_fcgid mod_perl
> mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value engine 1   1 last_modified 0   0
> xbithack  0   0
> 
> Apache Environment
> 
> Variable  Value PATH  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
> HTTP_HOST megafone.net HTTP_CONNECTION    keep-alive
> HTTP_USER_AGENT   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
> HTTP_ACCEPT   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING  gzip,deflate,sdch
> HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE  en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
> HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> HTTP_COOKIE   641ef5ba0c118d90a82725cd6f0147b3=407eef50ce583166fe1ad5ba994e5e80df8361faa%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A2592000%3Bi%3A3%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7D%7D;
> PHPSESSID=13jvjai04he94ampftecvajlt2;
> __atuvc=14%7C49%2C20%7C50%2C1%7C51%2C1%7C52%2C16%7C1; __utma=135072749.2076075542.1353974194.1357128691.1357145563.28; __utmb=135072749.12.10.1357145563; __utmc=135072749; __utmz=135072749.1353974194.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at megafone.net
> Port 80</address> SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
> SERVER_NAME   megafone.net SERVER_ADDR    91.121.200.124 SERVER_PORT  80
> REMOTE_ADDR   37.14.149.224
> DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/vhosts/megafone.net/httpdocs
> SERVER_ADMIN  abadantoni@gmail.com
> SCRIPT_FILENAME   /var/www/vhosts/megafone.net/httpdocs/phpinfo.php
> REMOTE_PORT   57054 GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1 SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
> REQUEST_METHOD    GET QUERY_STRING    no value REQUEST_URI    /phpinfo.php
> SCRIPT_NAME   /phpinfo.php
> 
> HTTP Headers Information
> 
> HTTP Request Headers HTTP Request GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1
> Host  megafone.net Connection keep-alive User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
> Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97
> Safari/537.11
> Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Encoding   gzip,deflate,sdch
> Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
> Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> Cookie    641ef5ba0c118d90a82725cd6f0147b3=407eef50ce583166fe1ad5ba994e5e80df8361faa%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A2592000%3Bi%3A3%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7D%7D;
> PHPSESSID=13jvjai04he94ampftecvajlt2;
> __atuvc=14%7C49%2C20%7C50%2C1%7C51%2C1%7C52%2C16%7C1; __utma=135072749.2076075542.1353974194.1357128691.1357145563.28; __utmb=135072749.12.10.1357145563; __utmc=135072749; __utmz=135072749.1353974194.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) HTTP Response Headers X-Powered-By  PHP/5.1.6 X-Powered-By  PleskLin
> Connection    close Transfer-Encoding chunked Content-Type    text/html
> 
> bz2
> 
> BZip2 Support Enabled Stream Wrapper support  compress.bz2:// Stream
> Filter support    bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress BZip2 Version  1.0.3,
> 15-Feb-2005
> 
> calendar
> 
> Calendar support  enabled
> 
> ctype
> 
> ctype functions   enabled
> 
> curl
> 
> CURL support  enabled CURL Information    libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b
> zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> 
> date
> 
> date/time support enabled Timezone Database Version   0.system Timezone
> Database  internal Default timezone   Europe/Berlin
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> date.default_latitude 31.7667 31.7667
> date.default_longitude    35.2333 35.2333
> date.sunrise_zenith   90.583333   90.583333
> date.sunset_zenith    90.583333   90.583333 date.timezone no value    no value
> 
> dom
> 
> DOM/XML   enabled DOM/XML API Version 20031129 libxml Version 2.6.26
> HTML Support  enabled XPath Support   enabled XPointer Support    enabled
> Schema Support    enabled RelaxNG Support enabled
> 
> exif
> 
> EXIF Support  enabled EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: exif.c,v 1.173.2.5
> 2006/04/10 18:23:24 helly Exp $ Supported EXIF Version    0220 Supported
> filetypes JPEG,TIFF
> 
> ftp
> 
> FTP support   enabled
> 
> gd
> 
> GD Support    enabled GD Version  bundled (2.0.28 compatible) FreeType
> Support   enabled FreeType Linkage    with freetype FreeType Version  2.2.1
> GIF Read Support  enabled GIF Create Support  enabled JPG
> Support   enabled PNG Support enabled WBMP Support    enabled XBM
> Support   enabled
> 
> gettext
> 
> GetText Support   enabled
> 
> gmp
> 
> gmp support   enabled
> 
> hash
> 
> hash support  enabled Hashing Engines md4 md5 sha1 sha256 sha384 sha512
> ripemd128 ripemd160 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3
> tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru gost adler32 crc32 crc32b
> haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4
> haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5
> haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
> 
> iconv
> 
> iconv support enabled iconv implementation    glibc iconv library
> version   2.5
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> iconv.input_encoding  ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> iconv.internal_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> iconv.output_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> 
> imap
> 
> IMAP c-Client Version 2004 SSL Support    enabled Kerberos
> Support   enabled
> 
> json
> 
> json support  enabled json version    1.2.1
> 
> libxml
> 
> libXML support    active libXML Version   2.6.26 libXML streams   enabled
> 
> mbstring
> 
> Multibyte Support enabled Multibyte string engine libmbfl Multibyte
> (japanese) regex support  enabled Multibyte regex (oniguruma)
> version   3.7.1
> 
> mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and
> converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public
> License version 2.1.
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mbstring.detect_order  no value    no
> value mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off mbstring.func_overload  0   0
> mbstring.http_input   pass    pass mbstring.http_output   pass    pass
> mbstring.internal_encoding    no value    no value
> mbstring.language neutral neutral mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
> mbstring.substitute_character no value    no value
> 
> mime_magic
> 
> mime_magic support    invalid magic file, disabled
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mime_magic.debug   Off Off
> mime_magic.magicfile  /usr/share/file/magic.mime  /usr/share/file/magic.mime
> 
> mysql
> 
> MySQL Support enabled Active Persistent Links 1 Active Links  1 Client
> API version   5.0.77 MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE    external
> MYSQL_SOCKET  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> MYSQL_INCLUDE -I/usr/include/mysql MYSQL_LIBS -L/usr/lib64/mysql
> -lmysqlclient
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mysql.allow_persistent On  On
> mysql.connect_timeout 60  60 mysql.default_host   no value    no value
> mysql.default_password    no value    no value mysql.default_port no
> value no value mysql.default_socket   no value    no value
> mysql.default_user    no value    no value
> mysql.max_links   Unlimited   Unlimited
> mysql.max_persistent  Unlimited   Unlimited mysql.trace_mode  Off Off
> 
> mysqli
> 
> MysqlI Support    enabled Client API library version  5.0.77 Client API
> header version    5.0.77 MYSQLI_SOCKET    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mysqli.default_host    no value    no
> value mysqli.default_port 3306    3306 mysqli.default_pw  no value    no
> value mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value mysqli.default_user    no
> value no value mysqli.max_links   Unlimited   Unlimited
> mysqli.reconnect  Off Off
> 
> openssl
> 
> OpenSSL support   enabled OpenSSL Version OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01
> Jul 2008
> 
> pcre
> 
> PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support    enabled PCRE
> Library Version   6.6 06-Feb-2006
> 
> PDO
> 
> PDO support   enabled PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
> 
> pdo_mysql
> 
> PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version  5.0.77
> 
> pdo_sqlite
> 
> PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x enabled PECL Module version 1.0.1 $Id:
> pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6 2006/01/01 12:50:12 sniper Exp $ SQLite
> Library   3.3.6
> 
> posix
> 
> Revision  $Revision: 1.70.2.3 $
> 
> pspell
> 
> PSpell Support    enabled
> 
> Reflection
> 
> Reflection    enabled Version $Id: php_reflection.c,v 1.164.2.33
> 2006/03/29 14:28:42 tony2001 Exp $
> 
> session
> 
> Session Support   enabled Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
> Registered serializer handlers    php php_binary wddx
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value session.auto_start Off Off
> session.bug_compat_42 Off Off session.bug_compat_warn On  On
> session.cache_expire  180 180 session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
> session.cookie_domain no value    no value session.cookie_lifetime    0   0
> session.cookie_path   /   / session.cookie_secure Off Off
> session.entropy_file  no value    no value session.entropy_length 0   0
> session.gc_divisor    1000    1000 session.gc_maxlifetime 1440    1440
> session.gc_probability    1   1 session.hash_bits_per_character   5   5
> session.hash_function 0   0 session.name  PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
> session.referer_check no value    no value
> session.save_handler  files   files
> session.save_path /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
> session.serialize_handler php php session.use_cookies On  On
> session.use_only_cookies  Off Off session.use_trans_sid   0   0
> 
> shmop
> 
> shmop support enabled
> 
> SimpleXML
> 
> Simplexml support enabled Revision    $Revision: 1.151.2.22 $ Schema
> support   enabled
> 
> sockets
> 
> Sockets Support   enabled
> 
> SPL
> 
> SPL support   enabled Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator,
> RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
> Classes   AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject,
> BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator,
> DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilterIterator,
> InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator,
> LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, NoRewindIterator,
> OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException,
> ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator,
> RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator,
> RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RuntimeException,
> SimpleXMLIterator, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplObjectStorage,
> SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
> 
> SQLite
> 
> SQLite support    enabled PECL Module version 2.0-dev $Id: sqlite.c,v
> 1.166.2.13 2006/04/18 14:30:15 iliaa Exp $ SQLite Library 2.8.17 SQLite Encoding  UTF-8
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value sqlite.assoc_case  0   0
> 
> standard
> 
> Regex Library Bundled library enabled Dynamic Library Support enabled
> Path to sendmail  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value assert.active  1   1 assert.bail   0   0
> assert.callback   no value    no value assert.quiet_eval  0   0
> assert.warning    1   1 auto_detect_line_endings  0   0
> default_socket_timeout    60  60 safe_mode_allowed_env_vars   PHP_    PHP_
> safe_mode_protected_env_vars  LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> url_rewriter.tags a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
> user_agent    no value    no value
> 
> sysvmsg
> 
> sysvmsg support   enabled Revision    $Revision: 1.20.2.3 $
> 
> tokenizer
> 
> Tokenizer Support enabled
> 
> wddx
> 
> WDDX Support  enabled WDDX Session Serializer enabled
> 
> xml
> 
> XML Support   active XML Namespace Support    active libxml2 Version  2.6.26
> 
> xmlreader
> 
> XMLReader enabled
> 
> xmlwriter
> 
> XMLWriter enabled
> 
> xsl
> 
> XSL   enabled libxslt Version 1.1.17 libxslt compiled against libxml
> Version   2.6.26 EXSLT    enabled libexslt Version    1.1.17
> 
> zlib
> 
> ZLib Support  enabled Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib:// Stream
> Filter support    zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate Compiled Version 1.2.3
> Linked Version    1.2.3
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value zlib.output_compression    Off Off
> zlib.output_compression_level -1  -1 zlib.output_handler  no value    no
> value
> 
> Additional Modules
> 
> Module Name dbase ionCube Loader sysvsem sysvshm
> 
> Environment
> 
> Variable  Value MYSQL_UNIX_PORT   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> SELINUX_INIT  YES CONSOLE /dev/console TERM   linux
> INIT_VERSION  sysvinit-2.86 PATH  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
> RUNLEVEL  3 runlevel  3 PWD   /etc/rc.d/init.d LANG   C PREVLEVEL N
> previous  N HOME  / SHLVL 4
> OPENSSL_CONF  /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/openssl.cnf
> _ /usr/sbin/httpd
> 
> PHP Variables
> 
> Variable  Value
> _REQUEST["641ef5ba0c118d90a82725cd6f0147b3"]  407eef50ce583166fe1ad5ba994e5e80df8361faa:4:{i:0;s:5:"admin";i:1;s:5:"admin";i:2;i:2592000;i:3;a:0:{}}
> _REQUEST["PHPSESSID"] 13jvjai04he94ampftecvajlt2
> _REQUEST["__atuvc"]   14|49,20|50,1|51,1|52,16|1
> _REQUEST["__utma"]    135072749.2076075542.1353974194.1357128691.1357145563.28
> _REQUEST["__utmb"]    135072749.12.10.1357145563
> _REQUEST["__utmc"]    135072749
> _REQUEST["__utmz"]    135072749.1353974194.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
> _COOKIE["641ef5ba0c118d90a82725cd6f0147b3"]   407eef50ce583166fe1ad5ba994e5e80df8361faa:4:{i:0;s:5:"admin";i:1;s:5:"admin";i:2;i:2592000;i:3;a:0:{}}
> _COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]  13jvjai04he94ampftecvajlt2
> _COOKIE["__atuvc"]    14|49,20|50,1|51,1|52,16|1
> _COOKIE["__utma"] 135072749.2076075542.1353974194.1357128691.1357145563.28
> _COOKIE["__utmb"] 135072749.12.10.1357145563
> _COOKIE["__utmc"] 135072749
> _COOKIE["__utmz"] 135072749.1353974194.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
> _SERVER["PATH"]   /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
> _SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]  megafone.net
> _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]    keep-alive
> _SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97
> Safari/537.11
> _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]   gzip,deflate,sdch
> _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]   en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
> _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> _SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]    641ef5ba0c118d90a82725cd6f0147b3=407eef50ce583166fe1ad5ba994e5e80df8361faa%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A2592000%3Bi%3A3%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7D%7D;
> PHPSESSID=13jvjai04he94ampftecvajlt2;
> __atuvc=14%7C49%2C20%7C50%2C1%7C51%2C1%7C52%2C16%7C1; __utma=135072749.2076075542.1353974194.1357128691.1357145563.28; __utmb=135072749.12.10.1357145563; __utmc=135072749; __utmz=135072749.1353974194.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
> _SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]   <address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at megafone.net Port 80</address>
> _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]    Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
> _SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]    megafone.net
> _SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]    91.121.200.124
> _SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]    80
> _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]    37.14.149.224
> _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]  /var/www/vhosts/megafone.net/httpdocs
> _SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"]   abadantoni@gmail.com
> _SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]    /var/www/vhosts/megafone.net/httpdocs/phpinfo.php
> _SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]    57054
> _SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]  CGI/1.1
> _SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]    HTTP/1.1
> _SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] GET
> _SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]   no value
> _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]    /phpinfo.php
> _SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]    /phpinfo.php
> _SERVER["PHP_SELF"]   /phpinfo.php
> _SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]   1357148792
> _ENV["MYSQL_UNIX_PORT"]   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> _ENV["SELINUX_INIT"]  YES
> _ENV["CONSOLE"]   /dev/console
> _ENV["TERM"]  linux
> _ENV["INIT_VERSION"]  sysvinit-2.86
> _ENV["PATH"]  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
> _ENV["RUNLEVEL"]  3
> _ENV["runlevel"]  3
> _ENV["PWD"]   /etc/rc.d/init.d
> _ENV["LANG"]  C
> _ENV["PREVLEVEL"] N
> _ENV["previous"]  N
> _ENV["HOME"]  /
> _ENV["SHLVL"] 4
> _ENV["OPENSSL_CONF"]  /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/openssl.cnf
> _ENV["_"] /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: Restarting httpd didn't help, btw.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a bug, it's how PHP is supposed to work. Restart your PHP server or call apc_clear_cache() from your code to clear the APC cache.

Comment: ¿¿¿¿How it is supposed to work???? It is supposed to keep an outdated cache even after you have modified a php file?? Are you supposed to restart the server or explicitely clear the cache every damn time you modify a php file? (and by the way how it has never happened before to me?) That doesn't make any sense. Cache makes sense until a file is modified. There's no reason in the world why one would want an outdated cached file to be kept.

Comment: From where should I call apc_clear_cache()? From a random script e.g. clearcache.php which would be like <?php acp_clear_cache() ?> and that would clear all the cache?

Comment: I ask this so that I can accept your answer as a workaround

Comment: By the way, the acronym "apc" doesn't even appear in my phpinfo(). Are you sure it's actually APC that is used in this case?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in xxx.php So, I don't even have APC apparently. Must be some other cache engine or something.